# Python key in a dictionary not defined error (NameError)

Tags: python

I want to declare a dictionary with empty keys and append the values later. I am trying this

```
>>> Dict = {"a","b","c","d"}
>>> dict([(key, []) for key in Dict])
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}
>>> Dict[a].append(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

why do i get this error?
Please help me fix this..

```
>>> Dict['a'].append(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the `a` -> `'a'`

Comment: Furthermore, `Dict` is a set. So you can't do what you are trying to do

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error you are seeing, because what you are doing here:

`Dict = {"a","b","c","d"}`

is creating a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and not a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Even though they share the *curly braces*, does not mean they are both one and the same.

if you do a `print(type(Dict))`, you will see you in fact have a `set` and not a `dict`:

```
>>> Dict = {"a","b","c","d"}
>>> print(type(Dict))
<type 'set'>
```

You seem to be looking for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), that takes a `list` as its *default* value structure:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> your_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> your_dict['a'].append(1)
>>> print(your_dict)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1]})
>>> print(your_dict['a'])
[1]
```